# Literal identifier in back ticks in scala

Tags: scala, identifier

As per the rule, "one or more of any character except a backquote, all enclosed in a pair of back-quotes", can be a valid identifier in scala. But the below one errors out.

```
scala> val `123` = "OneTwoThree"
<console>:5: error: ';' expected but double literal found.
         lazy val $result = 123
                                                 ^
<console>:9: error: ')' expected but double literal found.
       ""  + "123: String = " + _root_.scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime.replStringOf(123, 1000)
```

Am I missing something here ? Can someone please help. Thanks!

Comment: I unfortunately don't have an answer as my knowledge into the REPL is very limited but there are a decent number of things that work differently in REPL than they would in regular scala code. I tried the above in a Scala program and it seems to work, for what it is worth

Comment: As a reference, this seems to a be known issue: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/8456

Answer (score 4):

Gathering all the info in one answer so we can mark this question complete for the future visitors.

This is a known issue in the default Scala REPL. Follow the issue [here](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/8456)

This currently only happens with numbers as per the ticket suggests. There likely is a sanitation issue.

This issue has been fixed in [Ammomite](https://ammonite.io/) that provides a 3rd party, open source REPL, with [this commit](https://github.com/jameskoch/Ammonite/commit/d425ad5b6d54664f8acd6c261542f1e491f0839a). If you really need the REPL to support this feature, you can switch to Ammomite

Comment: Seems to work in [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/fS8UbszKSwyAFwTqoKgD9A) as well.

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks for the addition. Forgot to put the link I tested with